# web method not updating details on the sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, web-services

I am trying to update student details after they log in. I want to be able to update their password and email address when they click the button. Its

```
[WebMethod]
public bool EditAccount(Student student)
{
    bool UploadSuccess = false;
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblStudent set EmailAddress='" + student.EmailAddress + "', Password='" + student.Password + "'", cn);
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", student.EmailAddress);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", student.Password);
        int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        if (i != 0)
        UploadSuccess = true;
        return UploadSuccess;
     }
 }

 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Student edit = stu.EditAccount();
     edit.EmailAddress = txtEmail.Text;
     edit.Password = txtPassword2.Text;

     if (stu.EditAccount(edit))
     {
         Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Successful');</script>");
     }
     else
     {
         Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Password not matched');</script>");
     }                   
 }
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: What is `stu` in this line: `Student edit = stu.EditAccount();` ?

Comment: ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient stu = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();

Comment: cn.Open()?? or cm.open() ??

Comment: sorry posted the wrong method.

Comment: try to debug this line with `try-catch`  may be your are passing some invalid inputs. `int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i != 0)
            UploadSuccess = true;`

Comment: use try catch for god sake, and its web service so please try to log the errors somewhere, or else you will be stuck playing with small errors. Even i was stucked for a silly mistakes. :P

Comment: Please use _parameterized queries_. This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Comment: Why do you need a webmethod? Web methods are invoked from javascript, and need to be defined as static... Your webmethod is neither of these...

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be a mess try to rewrite it like this. Meanwhile `ExecuteNonQuery` `returns` number of affected rows. if you are trying to return something try to use `ExecuteScalar` or `Reader`

```
bool UploadSuccess = false;
int i;
cn.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblStudent set EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, Password=@Password", cn);
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", student.EmailAddress);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", student.Password);
    try
    {
        i=com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    cn.Close();
    if (i != 0)
        UploadSuccess = true;
    return UploadSuccess;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

`ExecuteNonQuery` method returns int.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public bool EditAccount(Student student)
{

    string cmdText = @"UPDATE tblStudent set [EmailAddress]=" + student.EmailAddress +
                      [Password]="+ student.Password +" where [StudentNumber]=" + student.StudentNumber;
    var con = new SqlConnection(constring));

    var SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand{
            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            CommandText = cmdText ,
            Connection = con 
         };
    try
     { 
        con.Open();
        int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i > 0)
            return true;
      }
      finally
      {
        con.close();
      }
        return false;
}
```

I would suggest using Stored Procedures instead of inline queries for better results.